# Jetpack Compose NavigationBar is slow/janky compared to XML

Tags: xml, performance, android-jetpack, navigationbar, smoothing

I was playing around with Jetpack Compose the other day and when I implemented a NavigationBar component I knew something was not right. It feels janky/laggy and not really like the navigation bar we're used to have on Android.

For demonstration purposes I have created one project where I have implemented a NavigationBar with Jetpack compose and one project where I have implemented it with XML and I noticed a big difference in Animation/Performance of the Jetpack Compose version.

Here is the Jetpack Compose implementation which feels laggy and just not smooth
[Jetpack Compose Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNGB5.gif)

Here is the XML implementation with very smooth/fluent animations
[XML implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sROl6.gif)

I have tried to update all my dependencies to have the latest version of Jetpack Compose Material Components.

I was expecting a richer/smoother experience of the Bottom Navigation Bar in Jetpack Compose

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Jetpack compose uses relatively new rendering engines than xml.

Compose has good performance in release builds compared to debug builds. But no where close to performance of xml.